# Browser document loaded

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to populate a grid with some data extracted from linkedin, im just trying to get it working for my own learning curve, BUT if I remove the line

```
MessageBox.Show("asdfasdfasdf")
```

the list "messages" only has 1 item, if I include the line above it does whats expected and I get 15 messages

Can someone explain?

```
public void extract_messages_received(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    triggered = false;
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
    browser.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://www.linkedin.com/inbox/messages/received"));
    browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
}

private void LoadMessages(string url)
{
    txtOutput.Text = @"http://www.linkedin.com" + url.Substring(6, url.Length - 6);
    if (!urls.Contains(url))
    {
        urls.Add(url);
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Navigate(new Uri(txtOutput.Text);

        loaded_message = false;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ReadMessages);
    }
}

private void ReadMessages(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (loaded_message == false)
    {        
        string url = ((WebBrowser)sender).Url.ToString();
        int loc1 = url.IndexOf("itemID") + 7;
        int loc2 = url.IndexOf("&", loc1);
        IEnumerable<string> name = null;
        IEnumerable<string> odate = null;
        IEnumerable<string> photo = null;
        IEnumerable<string> subject = null;
        IEnumerable<string> headline = null;
        string body = "";
        string id = url.Substring(loc1, loc2 - loc1);
        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("READ");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("classname").Equals("inbox-item-body"))
            {
                body = element.InnerText;
            }
            if (element.GetAttribute("classname").Equals("inbox-item-header"))
            {
                var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(element.InnerHtml);
                name = from foo in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='fn']") select foo.InnerText;
                odate = from foo in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='date']") select foo.InnerText;
                photo = from foo in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class='photo']") select foo.Attributes["src"].Value;
                subject = from foo in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3") select foo.InnerText;
                headline = from foo in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='headline']") select foo.InnerText;
            }
        }

        // ****
        MessageBox.Show("asdfasdfasdf");
        // ****

        messages.Add(new Messages()
        {
            ID = id,
            Subject = subject.First().ToString(),
            Headline = headline.First().ToString(),
            Sender = name.First().ToString(),
            Photo = photo.First().ToString(),
            SendDate = odate.First().ToString(),
            Body = body
        });

           // dataMessages.ItemsSource = messages;
    }
    loaded_message = true;
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!triggered)
    {
        triggered = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser web = sender as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("ol"))
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("classname").Contains("inbox-list "))
            {
                WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
                browser.Navigate("about:blank");
                browser.Document.Write(element.InnerHtml);
                HtmlElementCollection hrefTags = null;
                hrefTags = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
                foreach (HtmlElement a in hrefTags)
                {
                    if (a.OuterHtml.Contains("displayMBox"))
                    {
                        LoadMessages(a.GetAttribute("href"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a timing issue.

When you have the message box in there, `loaded_message` doesn't get set to `true` until after you close the message box, so the other events are processing up until the message box as well, with none of them settings `loaded_message` to true until you close the first message box.

If you close the messagebox quickly enough, you will probably see some number beteween 1 and 15.

Let's take a more simplistic example:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
            wb.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
    }

    bool shown = false;
    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!shown)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(shown);
            MessageBox.Show(shown.ToString());
            shown = true;
        }
    }
```

Now, if you watch the console, you will see a few `false` show up before the first message box is shown.  When I close the message box, I then see 4 more messageboxes because those were already queued up and waiting to show before `shown` got set to true.  If I comment out the messagebox, then I get only one message box shown and one `false` in the console.

Now, the question becomes, why did you add and need to check the `loaded_message` boolean variable.

My guess is that you only want to load each message only once.  If that is the case, keep track of each URL in a dictionary and maintain a bool for each URL:

```
    Dictionary<string, bool> loadedUrls = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
            string url = "http://stackoverflow.com/" + i;

            loadedUrls.Add(url, false);
            wb.Navigate(url);
        }
    }

    bool shown = false;
    void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (loadedUrls.ContainsKey(e.Url.OriginalString) && loadedUrls[e.Url.OriginalString] == false)
        {
            loadedUrls[e.Url.OriginalString] = true;
            Console.WriteLine(shown);
            shown = true;
        }
    }
```

I left `shown` in there to demonstrate that this new approach now works for each pass in the document completed event.  Your output window should have a `false` followed by 4 `true`.

Comment: Nice one John!!  Bingo ;-)